# how to make List<List> using List?

Tags: flutter

I have to make `List<List>` using `List`

```
  List<String> list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10' , '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18' , '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25'];
```

`list.length` will be no more than 25.

have to divide by 5 like

```
  int divide;
  
  divide = word.length ~/ 5;
```

and have to make `List<List>`

I don't know how to do it.

have to be

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],[21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
```

if `list.length is 23` have to be

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],[21, 22, 23]]
```

Comment: I would look at [sublist](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/sublist.html).  PS: Do you want List<String> (your first example)<or List<number> (subsequent examples)?

Comment: just one line will make the trick: `print(list.splitBeforeIndexed((i, _) => i % 5 == 0).toList());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one

```
List dataList = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10' , '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18' , '19', '20', '21', '22'];
List chunkList = [];
int chunkSize = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < dataList.length; i += chunkSize) {
    chunkList.add(dataList.sublist(i, i+chunkSize > dataList.length ? dataList.length : i + chunkSize)); 
  }
print(chunkList);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best one, you can try like below

```
List<List<String>> _getListInList(List<String> data) {
    final chunks = <List<String>>[];
    final chunkSize = 5;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += chunkSize) {
      chunks.add(
        data.sublist(
          i,
          i + chunkSize > data.length ? data.length : i + chunkSize,
        ),
      );
    }

    return chunks;
  }
```

Just Copy and Paste :D